# Drupal 7 PHP: Cardconnect Integration

Tags: php, drupal

I am trying payment gateway integration in drupal 7 using cardConnect.
I tried following code using [this link](https://developer.cardconnect.com/cardconnect-api/#authorization-service)

```
global $url, $user, $password;
echo "\nAuthorization Request\n";
$client = new CardConnectRestClient($url, $user, $password);
```

But, I am unable to find cardConnect library files. So, the above code is not working.
I am getting this error:

> Error: Class 'CardConnectRestClient' not found in include() (line 7 of
>   /var/www/html/c2sphase2/sites/all/modules/c2s/billingSystem/form_inc/c2s_billing_make_payment.inc).

Comment: The error says exactly what the problem is. I don't see how anyone could help you any more.

Comment: Read the developers document. But unable to figure out from where I can get this class function 'CardConnectRestClient'. But obvious it is not present  that is why it is showing not found error. If you know where I can get it please do share. Because in documentations I am unable to find it out. And getting freelancer websites in result that is what I not searching for. Also not getting related questions on stackoverflow. Thank you.

Comment: @Rashmi did you get the solution? I'm facing the same problem you mentioned.

Comment: Try searching github for  "CardConnect PHP REST client example" - it contains the code for the class.